# Error using `self` object in after_save callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, conditional-statements

I have two tables: **People** and **Car**:

- `Person has_many cars`
- `Car belongs_to person`.

I want to send email to the person when the `license_plate` of the car changed.

I have successfully made the Mail code but have problem in setting `if` condition inside `after_save` callback.

```
#Inside Person models
after_save :send_mail_notification, if: (self.cars.first.order('updated_at DESC').changed?)

def send_mail_notification(person)
    ...
end
```

I got this error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `cars' for #<Class:0x4852ba8>
```

So, I guess `self` isn't usable in callback? Any solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
after_save :send_mail_notification, if: Proc.new { |model| model.cars.order('updated_at DESC').first.changed? }
```

Comment: Now it says `NoMethodError: undefined method 'order' for #<Cars:0x4bd2378>` So is `order` also doesn't work?

Comment: change places order('updated_at DESC').first, because order should be called on relation, not object

Answer (score 1):

move it into the method?

```
after_save :send_mail_notification

def send_mail_notification(person)
    if (person.cars.first.order('updated_at DESC').changed?
      ..
    end
end
```

Comment: If I move it to the method, I still need callback to run it. So if my new callback doesn't have `if`, I think it will slowdown the performance?

Comment: Thanks for your time, I already found the answer from the guy above